# Nginx works with ip but returns 404 with domain name

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, nginx-config

I want to access a website served by Nginx with a domain name.

The domain points already to the IP and I can access the site using the IP + Port in the browser. But when entering the domain Nginx returns a 404 Not Found.

Here is my config:

```
 server {

 server_name a.b.com;
 listen 1337;
 listen [::]:1337;

 root /var/www/a.b.com/src;
 index index.html index.htm;

 location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: What do you mean _when entering a domain_? When you enter `http://a.b.com` it means to use default HTTP port 80, but if you  enter `http://a.b.com:1337` you should receive a response.

Comment: ok with the port it works. but how can i configure it so that it works without the port, because i have multiple  subdomains which point to this server but each should then point to another directory.

Comment: So you need multiply `server` blocks each listen on the default HTTP port 80 (or HTTPS port 443) with each own `server_name` specified.